# Jquery iteration through a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to add a row details function to my table with the use of Jquery. 
This is the problem I'm facing right now in the image below:

[image: This is how it looks right now]

The row details appear on every row upon click. I would like to assign it specifically to a row where the 'details' button on that row is clicked.

This is my Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
function details(fn) {
    return function() {
        var r = $(this).closest("tbody").find("tr.detailsRow")[fn]();
        $("tr.detailsRow").not(r).hide();
    };
};
$(".detailsRow").hide();
$detailsButtons = $(".detailsButton").click(details('toggle'));
$detailsButtons.closest("tr").find("input").click(details('show'));
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you finding the closest table body instead of the closest tr.detailsRow? What you're doing is essentially finding the closest table, which is the entire table, then finding all the tr.detailsRows in that table.

Comment: Wasn't quite sure about how it worked got it from an example, thank you for clearing it up for me!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function if you want to select the row just after the current one:

```
var r = $(this).closest("tr").next("tr.detailsRow")[fn]();
```

I have created some fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/XM9rz/ .

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. I wasn't quite sure about the code as I got it from an example, thanks for clearing it up!